# Filter dataframe on current date in spark using Java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've a spark dataframe with a column like this:

```
 Last_updated_date
    2020-09-25
    2020-09-30
```

It has some null records. I want to get the records where last_updated_date is less than the current date , it should include the nulls too. I'm using Java and my code is like

```
df.filter("last_updated_date" != current_date())
```

Error : incompatible operand types string and column

Comment: not working is too generic... can you elaborate what is the issue.

Comment: It states that "incompatible operand types string and column"

Comment: df.filter(col("last_updated_date") != current_date())

Comment: Tried that too , method filter (column) in the type Dataset<Row> is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)